# Need to know the div where jstree is created

Tags: javascript, html, css, jstree

I have many jstree on the same page. I want to apply special UI/dom effect on one specific tree.

I want to create a global variable in `jquery.jstree.js` file which is nothing but the div where jstree is initialized.

```
//I am using jst as a global object which knows in which div jstree is getting created.
if(jst.attr("id") == "special") {
  ...do something special...
}
```

Or if there is any other privilege in this library which lets me know the id of the jstree. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I want to know which id is in process currently.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery anyway, you can use `$("#special")` to select the DOM element with the id `special`. I'd certainly not mess up the `jquery.jstree.js` file. But I'm not sure, if I completely understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate what you want to achieve in case I did not understand correctly?

I believe that jsTree needs id to work properly so then you can define all you jsTree instances so its id starts with the string `jstree`

```
<div id='jstree_one'></div>
<div id='jstree_two'></div>
<div id='jstree_three'></div>
```

and then you can you use [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('[id^="jstree"]')
```

to apply the effect on all jstree instances. Or you can modify the selector to your needs.

Comment: Hi want to know which tree is currently initialized.

Comment: I am doing some changes in the api. For eg., if the `div` is `#special` I want to add a `span` element in `li`. That is why I want to know that so that the span effect does not affect all the jstree.

Comment: Then I believe you can use `.bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        alert("TREE IS LOADED");
    })`

Comment: I don't think it will work. Anyways, I have created a global variable `treeElement = special` which I set it before I initialize special tree. Then in the api at one place (line - 762) I have inserted an if condition which allows me to append a span element for that particular tree. It appears to be working fine. I couldn't find any better than this. I still hope api would be having this privilege to access main element at any time within the api.